# Geometry Math Olympiad Question

Tags: geometry, contest-math

> In the diagram below, *AD* is perpendicular to *AC* and $ ∠BAD = ∠DAE = 12^\circ$. If $AB + AE = BC$, find $∠ABC$. 
>   [image: Blockquote]
>
> The above is the diagram.

I came across this question in a Math Olympiad Competition and I am not sure how to solve it.

Comment: I do not actually know how to do the question on first sight. I am only able to find out the angles of $∠BAD$ , $∠DAE$ and $∠EAC$ but after that, I am not sure how to solve it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Proof.

Take $F$ on $\overrightarrow{BA}$ beyond $A$ such that $BF=BC$
$AE=AF$ and $\triangle AEF$ is isosceles.
$2\angle BAD=\angle BAE=\angle AEF+\angle AFE=2\angle AFE$
Thus $AD$ is parallel to $EF$.
$AD\bot AC$ and then $AC\bot EF$, which tell us $\square AECF$ is kite.
$\angle EFC=90^{\circ}-\angle FCA$, $\angle AFC=\angle AFE+\angle CFE=102^{\circ}-\angle FCA$
$\angle AFC=\angle ECF=2\angle FCA$, since $\triangle BCF$ is isosceles.
Hence, $\angle FCA=34^{\circ}$ and $\angle ABC=44^{\circ}$